# Is there data transfer between register/cache and main memory when calling malloc() and free()

Tags: c, memory-management, operating-system, disk

malloc() and free() are used to allocate and deallocate space in main memory.
Does that mean that there is no data transfer between the space in the main memory and the registers (or cpu caches) when calling them?

If there is no, are there similar operations/functions for allocating and deallocating space on disk without data transfer between the space on the disk and the main memory?

Thanks.

Comment: This question looks like very good downvote candidate due to "does not show any research effort" and especially "unclear or not useful". It looks like some abstract something resulting from misunderstanding of some coding problem. Please **explain** what **exactly** do you need to know and why. Illustrate your question with some practical `C` coding problem, although registers are more in the scope of the `assembly` language (where your answer would be more obvious)

Answer (score 2):

Well, the answer is either yes or no, but we don't know enough to say for sure, becase a lot of those things are determined by the underlying architecture; also, there are a lot of piece and moving parts in a modern processor.

But the practical answer in most any machine is "yes", because registers are involved int eh calling squence, in the context switch to allocate new physical memory and map it into the virtual memory, in the cache hit that happens with malloc first accesses that memory and when it first updates its datastructures.